# Firestore cloud function add multiple fields in one field

Tags: node.js, json, google-cloud-functions

I have a field names 'Options' and this field contains in itself 8 different checkboxes values. I am writing firestore cloud function using nodejs to post data in the collection where this field 'Options' is present. So far this is what i have written

```
exports.addCourse = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); 
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }
    else 
    {
        if (req.body.name != null && req.body.type != null && req.body.discipline != null && req.body.price_options != null
            && req.body.price != null && req.body.addon_prompt != null && req.body.addons != null && req.body.ship_price != null
            && req.body.keycode_bank != null && req.body.card_type != null && req.body.options != null && req.body.certificate_prompt != null
            && req.body.student_to_instructor_ratio != null && req.body.student_to_manikin_ratio != null && req.body.electronic_signature != null
            || req.body.name != undefined && req.body.type != undefined && req.body.discipline != undefined && req.body.price_options != undefined
            && req.body.price != undefined && req.body.addon_prompt != undefined && req.body.addons != undefined && req.body.ship_price != undefined
            && req.body.keycode_bank != undefined && req.body.card_type != undefined && req.body.options != undefined && req.body.certificate_prompt != undefined
            && req.body.student_to_instructor_ratio != undefined && req.body.student_to_manikin_ratio != undefined && req.body.electronic_signature != undefined ) {
            let docId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999 - 00000));
            let newCourse = {
                "name": req.body.name,
                "type": req.body.type, //1: Classroom session enabled 2. No Classroom session 
                "discipline": req.body.discipline,
                "price_options": req.body.price_options, //Registrations allowed with deposits or not?
                "price": req.body.price,
                "addon_prompt": req.body.addon_prompt,
                "addons": req.body.addons, //add addons api values will be sent here 
                "ship_price": req.body.ship_price,
                "keycode_bank": req.body.keycode_bank, //Keycode bank value will be sent here
                "card_type": req.body.card_type, //Card type value will be sent here
                "options": {
                    "certificate_prompt": req.body.certificate_prompt,
                    "student_to_instructor_ratio": req.body.student_to_instructor_ratio,
                    "student_to_manikin_ratio": req.body.student_to_manikin_ratio,
                    "electronic_signature": req.body.electronic_signature
                }
            }
            usersCourses.add(newCourse).then(snapshot => {
                res.send(200, {
                    "message": "Course was successfully created"
                })
            });


        } else {
            res.send(400, {
                "message": "All fields are required"
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Deployed this API and then hitted it with Postman but got an error that 'All field are required'. What am i doing wrong? Is this the right way to add multiple fields in 'Options' field??

Data that i am sending through postman is not real one as ther are no specific datatypes provided to properties in the API

Data

```
{
    "name": "req.body.name",
    "type": "req.body.type", 
    "discipline": "req.body.discipline",
    "price_options": "req.body.price_options",
    "price": "req.body.price",
    "addon_prompt": "req.body.addon_prompt",
    "addons": "req.body.addons",
    "ship_price": "req.body.ship_price",
    "keycode_bank": "req.body.keycode_bank", 
    "card_type": "req.body.card_type", 
    "options": {
        "certificate_prompt": "req.body.certificate_prompt",
        "student_to_instructor_ratio": "req.body.student_to_instructor_ratio",
        "student_to_manikin_ratio": "req.body.student_to_manikin_ratio",
        "electronic_signature": "req.body.electronic_signature"
    },
    "ceu_credits": "req.body.ceu_credits",
    "description": "req.body.description",
    "confirm_email": "req.body.confirm_email"

}
```

Comment: You can indeed populate a field with a JavaScript object like `options`, it will be saved as a map in a Firestore document. What is `usersCourses`? A collection I guess, but it does not seem to be defined. Do you see any error in the Cloud Functions log (in the Firebase console)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes it is collection and it is defined on the top. i just pasted the cloud function here. I just need to know if what i have written in my code is it right or wrong? Should this code be working when i hit it with postman along with the respective values?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I am seeing 400 both in postman and in logs

Comment: No other error in the Cloud Functions log? At **very first glance** your code looks ok. Are you sure all the conditions for the first if (req.body.name != null && req.body.type != null...) are met?? Have you tried to debug this part one by one?

Comment: if block is working fine. There is no other error in cloud function.

Comment: If you get an error that 'All field are required' it means that for this if block the condition is falsy. If it was a Firebase error (e.g. an error with the add() method) you would get a different error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198868/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-ahsan-nissar).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code (or Postman call) that invokes this Cloud Function.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for being late. I don't think that the postman call for invoking this cloud function has anything to do here because this API can take in anything from postman. Anyways i can still edit it but the data won't be real with specific data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `if` condition you are checking for values that come in the `options` property as if they came in the top level of the data you are sending on the request body.

Also you can just check for `null` values as you are using `!=` operator without type coercion.

If the data you are sending is the one you provided with the question, change your `if` condition content to (checking for values inside the `options` field, removing `undefined` checks):

```
req.body.name != null && req.body.type != null && req.body.discipline != null && req.body.price_options != null
&& req.body.price != null && req.body.addon_prompt != null && req.body.addons != null && req.body.ship_price != null
&& req.body.keycode_bank != null && req.body.card_type != null && req.body.options != null && req.body.options.certificate_prompt != null
&& req.body.options.student_to_instructor_ratio != null && req.body.options.student_to_manikin_ratio != null && req.body.options.electronic_signature != null
```

and change where you create the `newCourse` variable to:

```
let newCourse = {
    "name": req.body.name,
    "type": req.body.type, //1: Classroom session enabled 2. No Classroom session 
    "discipline": req.body.discipline,
    "price_options": req.body.price_options, //Registrations allowed with deposits or not?
    "price": req.body.price,
    "addon_prompt": req.body.addon_prompt,
    "addons": req.body.addons, //add addons api values will be sent here 
    "ship_price": req.body.ship_price,
    "keycode_bank": req.body.keycode_bank, //Keycode bank value will be sent here
    "card_type": req.body.card_type, //Card type value will be sent here
    "options": {
        "certificate_prompt": req.body.options.certificate_prompt,
        "student_to_instructor_ratio": req.body.options.student_to_instructor_ratio,
        "student_to_manikin_ratio": req.body.options.student_to_manikin_ratio,
        "electronic_signature": req.body.options.electronic_signature
    }
}
```

Now you can send the example data:

```
{
    "name": "req.body.name",
    "type": "req.body.type", 
    "discipline": "req.body.discipline",
    "price_options": "req.body.price_options",
    "price": "req.body.price",
    "addon_prompt": "req.body.addon_prompt",
    "addons": "req.body.addons",
    "ship_price": "req.body.ship_price",
    "keycode_bank": "req.body.keycode_bank", 
    "card_type": "req.body.card_type", 
    "options": {
        "certificate_prompt": "req.body.certificate_prompt",
        "student_to_instructor_ratio": "req.body.student_to_instructor_ratio",
        "student_to_manikin_ratio": "req.body.student_to_manikin_ratio",
        "electronic_signature": "req.body.electronic_signature"
    },
    "ceu_credits": "req.body.ceu_credits",
    "description": "req.body.description",
    "confirm_email": "req.body.confirm_email"

}
```

with postman and it should work.